# Non-Parametric Statistical Significance Test on Regression Slope

Tags: python, scipy, regression, scipy.stats, statistical-test

I have created a plot of the regression slope of sea surface temperatures (x) and an atmospheric variable (y). Although, I need to test the statistical significance of these trends using a non-parametric test (doesn't assume data is normally distributed). Specifically, I am trying to use the Mann-Whitney U-test as it was suggested by a reviewer (but open to whatever will work and allow me to compare to results from the Students T-test). To do this, I have already calculated the regression slope to compare to a situation when the slope is zero. Then, I created an array of zeros that is the same size as my regression array to put into the statistical function:

```
### Try out the Mann-Whitney U-test: #### DOESNT WORK RIGHT NOW!!!!! 
zero = np.zeros(np.shape(regression))   ### shape: (721,1440)
test = mannwhitneyu(zero, regression)   ### shape: (721,1440)
```

Although, after running the test, I end up with an array of only one dimension and size 1440:

```
psave = test[1]   ### This array is only a single dimension (1440)
```

Ultimately, I would like to end up with an array of p-values from a non-parametric test of the shape (721,1440) testing the significance of my regression slope. Thank you for any and all help!!

Comment: Mann-Whitney U-test compares two populations. I'm not sure how the regression data/results can be framed in this way. Can you provide more details on the test intent and/or context given by the reviewer?

Comment: The intent of the test is to mark grid points in which the regression slope is statistically significant from zero (or no regression slope) on gridded data. To start, I had 3D data (time, lat, lon), leaving only lat and lon after the regression. Specifically, my reviewer commented that as my data is not normally distributed, I cant use the Students T-test and was instead recommended to use a non-parametric test for significance (i.e. Mann-Whitney U-test).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough data to use a Mann-Whitney U-test on each slope value. If you have an input array of shape (721,1440), and an output array of shape (721,1440), then each U test has an input of size one.

Here's what happens if you do a U test of size one:

```
for i in range(-5, 5):
    print("regression slope", i, "pvalue", scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu([i], [0]).pvalue)
```

Output:

```
regression slope -5 pvalue 1.0
regression slope -4 pvalue 1.0
regression slope -3 pvalue 1.0
regression slope -2 pvalue 1.0
regression slope -1 pvalue 1.0
regression slope 0 pvalue 1.0
regression slope 1 pvalue 1.0
regression slope 2 pvalue 1.0
regression slope 3 pvalue 1.0
regression slope 4 pvalue 1.0
```

No matter what regression slope you put in, the output will always be a p-value of 1. In order to have a p-value other than 1, you need at least two values.

#### Alternative

You could do a U-test over the entire regression slope array. Example:

```
scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu(regression.flatten(), zeros.flatten())
```